# Drawing drop shadows with hardware acceleration

Tags: java, android, drawing

Am I correct in understanding there's no way to draw a standard, blurred drop shadow using the Canvas APIs unless you turn off hardware acceleration? Seems like Paint.setMaskFilter() can't be used, and while Paint.setShadowLayer() seems to work -- sort of -- it ignores the color you supply in the final parameter and uses the Paint's main color instead.

Comment: On device or in emulator?

Comment: Paint.setShadowLayer() works only with text when hardware acceleration is on.

Comment: I've verified that hardware acceleration is on (or at least I'm getting a `true` value for it), and yet I _do_ get _something_ for Paint.setShadowLayer(). It's the same color as the Paint itself, and it's clipped funny, but it's there. Does that make any sense?